# VSCode MJML extension is unresponsive, how to attach the CPU profiler?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mjml

I've just installed the MJML extension and upon trying to use it to view an .mjml file it doesn't work. I checked the "running extensions" and it shows this:

[image: running extensions tab shows mjml as "unresponsive" with a very long activation time].

Trying to figure out what's wrong vscode prompts me with this:

[image: did you attach the cpu-profile?]

But I have no idea how to do that? I'm new to using vscode so I'm unsure what steps to take next.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have installed these three extensions and it is working great on my PC. If it didn't help you can try installing MJML Windows App.

Comment: The Attila Buti MJML VSCode version 1.0.0 extension is deprecated. The MJML team maintains a fork shown in the extension list as version 1.0.1. Recommended; it fixes important errors. You're right: the MJML Windows App is good, too. The only thing there is that you have less control of upgrading to new versions. They don't update with every new version.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mjmlio.vscode-mjml. This is the right one at this moment. There's another extension in the marketplace with the same but it's deprecated/buggy.